# Enable LOG Messages in QGIS

Tags: qgis, error, debugging, log, logging

How to enable log message in QGIS? debug mode or verbose mode.

I put variable in my env but without success.

More informations to complete this question:

I would like to see messages of detail the transaction between QGIS and database. I'm another problem with QGIS see my another [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244712/persistence-in-qgis-under-oracle-workspace) my idea is discovery more informations to understand the cause of this problem. To me is important enable debug mode in QGIS or enable high level logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

define in your OS this environment variables

```
 export CPL_DEBUG=ON
 export CPL_LOG_ERRORS=ON
 export CPL_LOG=/tmp/log_qgis.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the method described by rbarbalho is now obsolete.

I found that one needs to set the following environment variables:

```
QGIS_DEBUG=9
QGIS_LOG_FILE=/tmp/path/to/qgis.log
```

Some debug levels (or maybe all?) will *not* be logged if running a standard installation. These levels are only available if you compile your own version, using `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`.